# Stripe.net issue changing customers plan

Tags: stripe.net

I am looking for somebody to point me in the correct direction to properly update a subscription plan using Stripe.net.

I need to allow customers to change plans. Its been awhile since I used this library and the way I had done it in the past has changed dramatically.

According to Stripe's API documentation I should be able to post to the subscription the new plan and it'll make the change and handle the prorating.

The issue is I do not see where to pass in the new plan's ID to the StripeSubscriptionService.Update() method. If I pass in the new plan ID I obviously get a no subscription found error.

Does anyone have a snippet they can share to get me pointed in the right direction here?

Do I need to manually invoice?

Answer (score 1):

I made the mistake of not looking into the StripeSubscriptionUpdateOptions class. They've added a PlanId there that appears to serve the purpose.